# Cron expression for every sept working day

Tags: cron, cronexpression

How to create a cronexprrssion for ever 1st September working day. It means omit Sunday

Comment: Is it your 1st homework of programming course? Why 1`java`? Why `webapp2`?

Comment: I've voted to close as off topic. Questions about cron expressions are not programming questions. I'm also removing the `java` and `webapp2` tags as they seem irrelevant.

Comment: I recommend you this nice tutorial to cron expressions: [CronTrigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want what @Duncan said (a cron expression that finds the first working day in September), then this should do:

```
0 0 0 1W 9 ? *
```

Results:

1. Tuesday, September 1, 2015
2. Thursday, September 1, 2016
3. Friday, September 1, 2017
4. Monday, September 3, 2018
5. Monday, September 2, 2019

Comment: I need 1st day of sep .. If sunday comes it works on monday otherwise default... Thanks advance

Comment: Actually i think he wants only 1st, not every working days. Even so, my answer is still wrong.

Comment: Can you please write some expected results? It's still unclear for me what you exactly want.

Comment: @CristianSulea As I understand it, working days are Monday - Saturday. OP wants a cron expression that finds the first working day in September. I.e. next year it will be Tue 1st Sept.

Comment: @Duncan Then maybe he can use my expression, since it returns first Monday in September (so first working day in September).

Comment: @CristianSulea The first Monday is not the same as the first working day.

Comment: @Duncan You're right. I think i did'it: `0 0 0 1W 9 ? *` I will update my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to recognise Saturday as a working day? This solution is great for most people, for whom Saturday is a non-working day. It seems like the OP needs to include Saturday.

Comment: I think is not with only one expression, because in the docs weekdays = (Monday-Friday). Maybe is possible with some sort of intersection with results from another expression where he can specify first saturday, something like `SAT#1`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the format:

```
+---------------- minute (0 - 59)
|  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
|  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

This should make it:

```
+---------------- at minute 0
|  +------------- at hour 0
|  |  +---------- at day 1
|  |  |  +------- at month 9 -> September
|  |  |  |  +---- at day 1 to 6, that is, all but Sunday
|  |  |  |  |
0  0  1  9 1-6 /your/path/ /your/script
```

Comment: How to write script??

Comment: This you have to do yourself. Read some tutorial (google it, there are many) and then debug with http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info